# Convert PowerShell command to C#

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm using an azure function with this single line powershell code to trigger Azure Runbook

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri 'https://s16events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token='
```

I want to do the same using C# language Azure Function

Comment: Why would you create a function with the sole purpose of triggering a runbook? That is like lighting a match to light a match to light a stick of dynamite

Comment: There are a few ways of doing this in C#. This is just a POST call. Azure or no Azure wouldnt matter with what you are basically trying to do

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple post request, there're a lot of examples, you can take a look at this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request).

A simple code example:

```
using System.Net.Http;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.PostAsync("your_url", null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

And just feel free to modify this code to meet your need.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting when I apply this code to azure function
Missing a trigger argument named 'req'.

Comment: Please let me know how I can use this in Azure Function

Comment: @Joshua, please share me your code you have written(and hide the personal info like credentials etc.).